# How to find classes by multiple annotations from classpath?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'd like to find all classes from classpath that have two annotations defined.

Usually when EITHER one of the annotations is required, I could look them up as follows (**OR** matching):

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Entity.class));
provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(CustomAnnotation.class));
Set<BeanDefinition> beans = provider.findCandidateComponents("com.xyz.abc");
```

What would I have to change if I need **AND** matching, so that only classes having *both* annotations are returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you thought about creating your own filter? Something like:

```
final TypeFilter entityFilter = new AnnotationTypeFilter(Entity.class);
final TypeFilter customFilter = new AnnotationTypeFilter(CustomAnnotation.class);
TypeFilter andFilter = new TypeFilter {
    boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader, MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory) throws IOException {
        return entityFilter.match(metadataReader, metadataReaderFactory) && customFilter.match(metadataReader, metadataReaderFactory);
    }
};
provider.addIncludeFilter(andFilter);
```

Comment: I didn't know this is possible, thank you! It gets even better using java8: `TypeFilter AND_FILTER = (metadataReader, metadataReaderFactory) ->
  entityFilter.match(metadataReader, metadataReaderFactory) && customFilter.match(metadataReader, metadataReaderFactory);`